# Javascript String to JSON

Tags: javascript

How to can get this

```
var myString = 'a,b';
```

in the following in most efficient way

```
var myObject = { a:1, b:1};
```

I need 1 to be associated with each param. Thank you.

Comment: Please take the time to read [what JSON is](http://www.json.org/). The first paragraph would suffice, I think.

Comment: You could try `// Abrakadabra`, but it might fail.

Comment: What are you asking exactly, how does what get into what? That first line is an error? You missing ""?

Comment: @jAndy booo, I wrote **p00f**

Comment: beating the computer works sometimes when Abrakadabra fails lol..

Comment: @Neal: haha - I have to apologize you know I'm not like that usually, but 'nuff is 'nuff sometimes.

Comment: Sorry !!!! Hit Enter too soon :)

Comment: Ummmm enter does **not** submit a question... It just adds a line to the post.... @MeUnagi

Comment: @Neal: It does if you're editing the tags *(in Firefox anyway)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing your string is really defined as

```
var myString = 'a,b';
```

then you can get your object as

```
var obj = {};
var t = myString.split(',');
for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++) obj[t[i]] = 1;
```

This would make an obj just like

```
var obj = { a:1, b:1};
```

Note that I didn't get your goal so this might be useless...

**A side remark :**

JSON is a text format used for data exchange. There is nothing like a JSON object. `{ a:1, b:1}` is just a plain javascript object with two properties.

If what you want is really JSON, you may do

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Tis would be equivalent to

```
var myJSON = '{"a":1,"b":1}';
```

Comment: this is a ridiculouse answer..., if it didn't have the last line I would have considered to even downvote :p

Comment: @jAndy Why is this ridiculous ? I does the required job (or at least the requested one).

Comment: Thank you dystroy for quick and elaborate answer. Just the script I was looking for. Sorry about the silly mistakes regarding string closure and calling object a JSON. Had a long day. Thank you, you guys are the best !!!!

Answer (score 1):

`var myString = a,b;` does not do what you think it does.

What that does it set `myString`  equal to the value of `a` and `b` as a `undefined`.

To do what you want to do, just write this:

```
var myJSON = { a:1, b:1};
```

and **p00f**, it just works.

---

*The above was applicable before the ninja edit of the OP.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` and `.reduce()` for this.

```
var result = myString.split(',')
                     .reduce(function(obj, key) {
                         return obj[key] = 1, obj;
                     }, {});
```

You'll need a shim for older JavaScript implementations.

Comment: To be more precise about the "older JavaScript implementations", this won't work with IE8 (not a critic, just a precision).

Comment: @dystroy: That's a fair clarification. I'm being lazy today.